# How to grep the outputs of awk, line by line?

Tags: awk, grep, pipe

Let's say I have the following text file:

`$ cat file1.txt` outputs

```
MarkerName  Allele1 Allele2 Freq1   FreqSE  P-value Chr Pos
rs2326918   a   g   0.8510  0.0001  0.5255  6   130881784
rs2439906   c   g   0.0316  0.0039  0.8997  10  6870306
rs10760160  a   c   0.5289  0.0191  0.8107  9   123043147
rs977590    a   g   0.9354  0.0023  0.8757  7   34415290
rs17278013  t   g   0.7498  0.0067  0.3595  14  24783304
rs7852050   a   g   0.8814  0.0006  0.7671  9   9151167
rs7323548   a   g   0.0432  0.0032  0.4555  13  112320879
rs12364336  a   g   0.8720  0.0015  0.4542  11  99515186
rs12562373  a   g   0.7548  0.0020  0.6151  1   164634379
```

Here is an awk command which prints `MarkerName` if `Pos >= 11000000`

```
$  awk '{ if($8 >= 11000000) { print $1 }}' file1.txt
```

This command outputs the following:

```
MarkerName
rs2326918
rs10760160
rs977590
rs17278013
rs7323548
rs12364336
rs12562373
```

Question: I would like to feed this into a `grep` statement to parse another text file, `textfile2.txt`. Somehow, one pipes the output from the previous `awk` command into `grep AWKOUTPUT textfile2.txt`

I would like each row of the awk command above to be `grep`ped against `textfile2.txt`, i.e.

```
grep "rs2326918" textfile2.txt
## and then 
grep "rs10760160" textfile2.txt
### and then 
...
```

Naturally, I would save all resulting rows from `textfile2.txt` into a final file, i.e.

```
$ awk '{ if($8 >= 11000000) { print $1 }}' file1.txt | grep PIPE_OUTPUT_BY_ROW textfile2.txt > final.txt
```

How does one `grep` from a pipe line by line?

EDIT: To clarify, the one constraint I have is that `file1.txt` is actually the output of a previous pipe. (I'm trying to simplify the question somewhat.) How would that change the answer?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear but what is clear is that your currently accepted answer is definitely NOT how to do anything. If you'd like help then [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **bash** to do this:

```
bash-3.1$ echo "rs2326918" > filename2.txt
bash-3.1$ (for i in `awk '{ if($8 >= 11000000) { print $1 }}' file1.txt  |
    grep -v MarkerName`; do grep $i filename2.txt; done)  > final.txt
bash-3.1$ cat final.txt
rs2326918
```

Alternatively,

```
bash-3.1$ cat file1.txt | (for i in `awk '{ if($8 >= 11000000) { print $1 }}' |
    grep -v MarkerName`; do grep $i filename2.txt; done)  > final.txt
```

The switch `grep -v` tells **grep** to reverse its usual activity and print all lines that **do not match** the pattern.  This switch "inVerts" the match.

Comment: The one constraint I have is that `file1.txt` is actually the output of a previous pipe. (I'm trying to simplify the question somewhat.) How would that change the answer?

Comment: The part within the `()` is a subprocess, so you can remove `file1.txt` from the above and pipe right to `(for ...)`.

Comment: Could you explain more why you use `grep -v  MarkerName`? This would help learners like me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: deprecated backticks, UUOC, non-idiomatic awk syntax, unquoted variables, unnecessary commands and pipes, etc...

Answer (score 4):

**awk** + **grep** solution:

```
grep -f <(awk '$8 >= 11000000{ print $1 }' file1.txt) textfile2.txt > final.txt
```

---

- `-f file` - obtain patterns from `file`, one per line

Comment: The one constraint I have is that `file1.txt` is actually the output of a previous pipe. (I'm trying to simplify the question somewhat.) How would that change the answer?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, before changing the answer, someone should change the question

Answer (score 1):

only using **awk** can do this for you:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && NR==FNR {if ($8 >= 110000000) a[$1]++;next} \
   { for(i in a){if($0~i) print}}' file1.txt file2.txt> final.txt
```

Comment: The one constraint I have is that `file1.txt` is actually the output of a previous pipe. (I'm trying to simplify the question somewhat.) How would that change the answer?

Comment: To awk the piped output from `awk`, it appears this could work:
` PIPE | awk 'NR==FNR && $8 >= 110000000 { a[$1]++; next } \
    {for (i in a) if (i~$0) print}' file2.txt > final.txt`